# how to redirect from axios in react native & pass data to the route

Tags: react-native

i have a axios in react native when  post method is success i want to go to **/home** route and pass **data56** to **home route**

```
    axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/details', Data56)

      .then(() => {
       
        window.location.href = '/Home';
      })
```

what i am trying to do is make a **session** in home route  it will be better if  i can access data sutable for creating session in **/home** route

Comment: Hi, so from my understanding. You want to pass params to `/Home` , right? and that `Home` is a Screen, right?

Comment: yes i want to pass data56 to /home

Comment: does it needs to be route? Why don't you use `navigation.navigate`. I'll show you an example in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using route, why don't you just use something like this `navigation.navigate("ScreenName", {data: Data56})`

Here's the example:

```js
      axios
        .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/details', Data56)

        .then((res) => {
          navigation.navigate('ScreenName', { data: res.data });
        });
```

On the Screen component:

```js
const Screen = ({
  navigation,
  route,
}) => {
  const data = route.params.data;

...
```

Comment: pls tell me how to access it  in that scrren

Comment: @jisaks, just want to confirm things. You're using `react-native` not `react` right?
If yes, then you need to read about `react-navigation` here. [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).
It will tell you all about navigating between screens in `react-native`

Comment: yes i am using react native

Comment: @jisaks, have you created the `navigator`, `screen` component, etc?

Comment: yes i have created all i just want to pass that data to that screen now

Comment: referral error property navigation does not exist  i am getiing this eror

Comment: @jisaks, can you share the component code? I need to see more than the API call.